# Application of stokes theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, stokes-theorem

I was reviewing some class notes and I found the following problem:
Let $$F(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{-yz}{x^2+y^2},\frac{xz}{x^2+y^2},e^z\right)$$
and let $\gamma:\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
z+1&=&x^2+y^2\\
z&=&3
\end{array}\right.$ a curve traversed once counterclockwise when viewed from the point $(0,0,4)$. Calculate $\displaystyle\int_CF\cdot dr$.

I have used Stokes' theorem arriving at the following:
$$\displaystyle\int_CF\cdot dr=\iint_R rot F\cdot \vec{n} dA=\int_R\langle \frac{-x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},0\rangle\cdot \langle 0,0,1\rangle dA=0.$$

But my doubt enters when I see that the vector field F is not continuous on the z axis, and the surface passes through $(0,0,-1)$. So my result is still valid? or how can I solve this exercise?

Comment: Yep you are correct that you shouldn't use Stokes' theorem here. Try replacing $x^2+y^2$ since it is a fixed value on the curve.

Comment: @Keshav I know, I'm also under the impression that I shouldn't use Stokes, but that problem lies in the "Stokes theorem" topic. So I'm confused, if you could help me with a sketch solution that would be great.

Comment: If the normal is pointing straight up all the time then the surface is flat and thus does not pass through $(0,0,-1)$. The surface you used is just a disk in the plane $z=3$. It does touch the z axis, though, and it is indeed not continuous there. So you cannot directly apply Stokes in this way, you would need to puncture etc. which is probably not what is intended.

Comment: Instead you can work directly by just parametrizing by the angle.

Comment: @Ian Could you please show your idea of "puncture"? I haven't seen such problems before as I always played with continuous fields.

Comment: By "puncture" I mean you can consider something like an annulus instead of a disk to avoid having the singularity inside the domain. (This is an important trick in the study of PDEs.) It will still add another piece of boundary, however, which you will need to take care of. With any luck it is easier to do the integral over the inner circle than it is over the outer circle (which is not actually true here, the difficulty is exactly the same over any circle with center on the z axis).

Comment: @Ian I understand, thanks for your comment and the idea to attack other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the vector field is not defined at any point on z-axis, I can suggest below two approaches.

- Directly calculate the line integral (more straightforward in this case)
- Define a surface with the same boundary which does not cross z-axis; for example a cylinder of radius $2$

Using first approach,

$z +1  = x^2 + y^2 \implies r^2 = 4 ~$ at $z = 3$

$ \lambda(t) = (2 \cos t, 2 \sin t, 3); t \in (0, 2\pi)$

$\lambda'(t) = (- 2 \sin t, 2 \cos t, 0)$

$ \displaystyle F(\lambda(t)) = \left(- \frac{6 \sin t}{4},  \frac{6 \cos t}{4}, e^3\right)$

$\displaystyle \int_C \vec F (\lambda(t)) \cdot \lambda'(t) ~ dt = 6 \pi$

Using second approach, we parametrize the cylindrical surface $S$ as,

$\phi(z, t) = (2 \cos t, 2 \sin t, z); t \in (0, 2\pi), z \in (0, 3)$

$\phi_z \times \phi_t = (- 2 \cos t, - 2 \sin t, 0)$

$ \displaystyle \nabla \times \vec F = \left( - \frac{\cos t}{2}, - \frac{\sin t}{2}, 0 \right)$

So the surface integral is,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^3 \int_0^{2\pi} (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot (\phi_z \times \phi_t) ~ dt ~ dz = 6 \pi$

Please note the cylindrical surface has two boundaries, $C: r = 2, z = 3$ and $C_0: r = 2, z = 0$.

We have, $~\displaystyle \int_C \vec F \cdot dr - \int_{C_0} \vec F \cdot dr = \iint_S (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot dS = 6 \pi$

You can easily see that the line integral over $C_0$,   boundary at $z = 0$, is zero.

That leads to $\displaystyle \int_C \vec F \cdot dr = 6 \pi$

Comment: Thank you very much for your two approaches right now I start to analyze them. A query: If the same field $F$ had had $rot F=0$, that is "a conservative field" (but discontinuous on the z axis), could I say that its line integral with respect to a closed curve is zero or should I do the math? how did you just mention them?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can define a surface with two boundaries, not crossing z-axis. We usually do that when line integral over the given boundary is difficult to evaluate. The idea is to choose the other boundary such that it is easier to evaluate line integral on that boundary. Since curl of the vector field is zero, the line integral over both boundaries are cancelling each other and so once you know the line integral over one boundary, you know the other.

Comment: Great, thank you very much, it was clear to me what you said. I made a new question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4402130/691503). Following your idea it is enough to just find a suitable surface and take advantage of the fact that the curl of $F$ is $(0,0,0)$. I would really appreciate it if you could look at the new question. Thanks in advance.