# Discontinuous vector field with curl 0

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, stokes-theorem

Let $S$ be a part of the paraboloid $z=1-x^2-y^2$ such that $z\geq 2|y|$. They ask to calculate
$$
\int_C\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy+\frac{1+e^z}{1+z^2}dz
$$
where the curve $C$ is traversed once in an anticlockwise direction if it is observed from the point $(0,0,1)$.

It is easy to see that the curl of $F$ is $(0,0,0)$. So my initial idea was to use Stokes' theorem with which the answer would be zero.
[image]

But realizing that $F$ is not a continuous field this is not possible, now in reality it would be necessary to look for a surface that has two borders: one of them $C$ and another $C_0$ (which would be easier to calculate). The following occurs to me, taking the same surface but bounded above with $z=15/16$. That would make the new surface no longer go through the z axis.

**My attempt**

Let $\lambda(t)=(\frac{1}{4}\cos t,\frac{1}{4}\sin t,\frac{15}{16})$ then $\lambda'(t)=(-\frac{1}{4}\sin t,\frac{1}{4}\cos t,0)$. And we have $F(\lambda(t))=(-4\sin t,4\cos t,\frac{1+e^{15/16}}{1+(15/16)^2})$.
\begin{align}
\int_{C_0} F\cdot dr&=\int_{C} F\cdot dr+\iint_S (\nabla\times F)\cdot dS=\int_C F\cdot dr\\
\int_{C_0} F\cdot dr&=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2 t+\sin^2 tdt=2\pi
\end{align}

Comment: My suggestion would be to just do the direct line integral

Comment: @MathLover Yes, I am just doing it, I just want to practice doing it with another method since I want to learn how to use it well, to be sure of what I am doing.

Comment: In that case, you should take simpler curves first to apply the same. In any case, for this question, you could still think of a cylinder with the other boundary as $x^2 + y^2 = 1, z = -100$ for example.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the curve $z=0$ rather than $z=9/10$? The curl is zero everywhere, not just on $z\ge|2y|$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I think that's simpler, but it intersects curve C. Isn't there a problem?

Comment: Why would it be? You can convince yourself that the integral anticlockwise around $C_0$ and then clockwise back around $C$ can be split into four integrals: anticlockwise around "left half" of $C_0$, clockwise around "left half" of $C$, clockwise around "right half" of $C$, anticlockwise around "right half" of $C_0$. Now, the first two terms give you an integral around one closed curve ("left half") which is zero, and the two other terms give you an integral around another closed curve ("right half") which is also zero. Thus the total is zero.

Comment: @Zaragosa Did you get my earlier point?

Comment: @MathLover Yes, only that I was thinking a bit about $z=-100.$ I know that it does not matter what value of $z$ it takes because it will still disappear. I edited my question with my intent, I basically put that radius to make it more visual but you could have any radius as long as it is guaranteed not to intersect with curve $C$. I think...

Comment: Yes. It is not a circular cylinder with fixed radius. Here is how I would like you to think about - one end of the cylinder is curve $C$ and the other end is a circle of radius $r$ at a value of $z$, clear from $C$.

Comment: @MathLover +1 Thank you for that comment it was very enlightening.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 2):

What you've argued is that if $C_0$ is a second curve within your surface that circulates once counterclockwise around the "north pole" of the paraboloid, then $\int_C F\,dx = \int_{C_0} F\,dx$. You can take $C_0$ to be the intersection of the paraboloid with the plane $z=9/10$ if you like, as long as you're sure that the plane does not intersect $C$.

For this transformation to make sense, you need the integral around $C_0$ to be easier to compute than that around $C$; for instance you might notice that in cylindrical coordinates, $F = d\theta$.